# lua checking multiple values for equailty

Tags: string, if-statement, properties, lua, roblox

I like to make games in Roblox and I code in lua. Well coding games I find myself asking if a value equals another value a lot and it can make really long lines of code and can be quite repetitive. 
For example: 
if x.ClassName == 'Shirt' or
 x.ClassName == 'Accessory' or
 x.ClassName == 'Pants' or
 x.ClassName == 'CharacterMesh' then 
-- do thing

end 
doing that not only can be very messy but is also just asking the same thing over and over again slightly modified.
 I was wondering if there was a way in lua to ask if a value equals multiple diferant separate values
For example:
if x.ClassName == ( 'Shirt' or 'Accessory' or 'Pants' or 'CharacterMesh' ) then 
-- do thing
end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no native way to do this in Lua but you can implement a helper function `set` to achieve that.

```
function set(...)
   local ret = {}
   for _,k in ipairs({...}) do ret[k] = true end
   return ret
end

local classname = 'Shirt'
if set('Shirt', 'Accessory', 'Pants', 'CharacterMesh')[classname] then
   print('true')    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if string.match('/Shirt/Accessory/Pants/CharacterMesh/', '/'..x.ClassName..'/') then ... end
```

but it's unlikely to be any faster than the if chain you have.