# Checking if a character in a set position matches a certain value

Tags: optimization, lua

I have a string of letters, `YYY` or `NNN` etc. and I want to test if, say, the first character is a `Y`, or the middle character is a `Y`.

This needs to happen multiple times over different lines, checking for different values.

I do have a solution which works (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501359/lua-checking-multiple-values-for-equailty)):

```
matchCode1 = 'YYY'

function set(...)
   local ret = {}
   for _,k in ipairs({...}) do ret[k] = true end
   return ret
end

if set('YYY', 'YYN', 'YNY', 'YNN')[matchCode1] then
   print('true')
else 
  print('false')
end
```

I was just wondering if there is a simpler way, given that I only need to check if the (in this case) first letter in the string is a `Y`.

`matchCode1` can be any combination of `Y` and `N` but is always 3 characters.

The other cases I will check are that the second character is `Y` and the third is `Y` and then if ALL are `Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.find`. `string.find` will take a Lua pattern and search for a match in the given string, it will return the indices of the char.

This example only looks at the first instance of `Y`:

```
function checkMatchCode(code)
  startIndex = code:find('Y')

  if startIndex == 1 or startIndex == 2 then
    print(code .. ': true')
  else 
    print(code .. ': false')
  end
end

checkMatchCode('YYY')
checkMatchCode('YNY')
checkMatchCode('NYY')
checkMatchCode('NYN')
checkMatchCode('NNY')
checkMatchCode('NNN')
```

Output:

```
YYY: true
YYN: true
YNY: true
NYY: true
NYN: true
NNY: false
NNN: false
```

---

You can also use `string.gmatch` similarly to create a table of your match results

This example checks if each char in the string is `Y`:

```
function checkMatchCode(code)
  local results = {}

  for char in code:gmatch('.') do
    local charPosition = #results + 1
    if char == 'Y' then
      results[charPosition] = true
    else
      results[charPosition] = false
    end
  end

  if results[1] and results[2] then -- using an and here to show the difference 
    print(code .. ': true')
  else 
    print(code .. ': false')
  end
end

checkMatchCode('YYY')
checkMatchCode('YNY')
checkMatchCode('NYY')
checkMatchCode('NYN')
checkMatchCode('NNY')
checkMatchCode('NNN')
```

Output:

```
YYY: true
YYN: true
YNY: false
NYY: false
NYN: false
NNY: false
NNN: false
```

`string.gmatch` is a more powerful option if you care about matching multiple char or having a table of all the match results to munipluate else where in your code.

`string.find` is a quick check that can tell you if there is at least 1 `Y`and where that `Y` is, it does not care if there is 1 or 3 `Y`'s you will only ever get the information on the first match.

Comment: Ah that's fab. I hadn't thought of using string.find in that way!